# Can miner pay transaction fee with coinbase (if maturity is disabled)?

Tags: transactions, protocol

If I understand correctly,

1. the first transaction in a block may collect transaction fees (difference between inputs and outputs) from the following transactions in the same block; and
2. subsequent transactions may use outputs from previous transactions in the same block.

If the block maturity check is disabled, so that newly minted coins may be utilized immediately, can a circular dependency of transactions arise, i.e., a miner uses coins generated from the coinbase to pay for transaction fee of a transaction in the same block, but the fee is then returned back to themselves (collected by the coinbase)?

Answer (score 1):

If your altcoin removes the maturity check, I don't see why not. The only prerequisite would be that the fee for the transaction spending the coinbase input must be decided before building the tx, which isn't very hard.